# Backspace in modifiers?

Tags: expresso-store, modifiers

I'm using [Exp-resso Store](https://exp-resso.com/docs/store/). Is there a way to use the `backspace` parameter in the {modifiers} tag? For the cart view, I'm hoping to list the modifiers that are being used, something like this:

```
{modifiers backspace="2"}
    <strong>{modifier_name}:</strong> {modifier_value}
{/modifiers}
```

That would output something like: **Color:** Blue, **Size:** X-Large

Thanks a ton,
Brennan

Answer (score 2):

There's no backspace parameter.

One possible solution I can think of would be to use css and the `:last-child` selector. For example:

```
<div class="modifiers">
    {modifiers}
        <span class="modifier"><strong>{modifier_name}:</strong> {modifier_value}<span class="separator">,</span></span>
    {/modifiers}
</div>
```

With css:

```
.modifiers .modifier:last-child .separator {
    display: none;
}
```

This would work in [all browsers except IE8](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-sel3), and it doesn't seem like a big deal if IE8 users see an extra comma.